# Spock Where Block throws nullpointexception in Grails 3 Integration Test

Tags: grails, integration-testing, spock, grails-3.0

I am trying to run an Grails 3 service integration test with a spock where block. However, I am getting a null pointer exception (see below). If I run it as a succession of then/when blocks it works. Any idea what am I missing?

```
@Integration
@Rollback
class PersistenceAutoCompleteTermServiceIntegrationSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    @Autowired
    PersistenceAutoCompleteTermService persistenceAutoCompleteTermService

    @Unroll
    void "fetchAllLikeTerm tests"() {

        setup:
            new PersistenceAutoCompleteTerm(name: 'Milkshake').save()
            new PersistenceAutoCompleteTerm(name: 'Oat Milk').save()
            new PersistenceAutoCompleteTerm(name: 'Special K').save()

        when:
            List<String> names = persistenceAutoCompleteTermService.fetchAllLikeTerm(term)

        then:
            names.size() == expected_result

        where:
        term        | expected_result
        "Milk"      | 2
        "milk"      | 2
    }
}
```

Fails with

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.executeAndRollback(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:64)
    at com.shoptimix.api.persistence.PersistenceAutoCompleteTermServiceIntegrationSpec.fetchAllLikeTerm tests(PersistenceAutoCompleteTermServiceIntegrationSpec.groovy)
```

However this works:

```
@Unroll
void "fetchAllLikeTerm tests"() {

    setup:
        new PersistenceAutoCompleteTerm(name: 'Milkshake').save()
        new PersistenceAutoCompleteTerm(name: 'Oat Milk').save()
        new PersistenceAutoCompleteTerm(name: 'Special K').save()

    when:
        List<String> names = persistenceAutoCompleteTermService.fetchAllLikeTerm("Milk")

    then:
        names.size() == 2

    when:
        names = persistenceAutoCompleteTermService.fetchAllLikeTerm("milk")

    then:
        names.size() == 2
}
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. To clarify a bit the problem is specific to using @Unroll. Also it is only a problem for the very first test.

Comment: I have this exact issue, and Jon's workaround worked well. Is this being tracked in a GitHub issue?